# How to filter ListView adapter by ignoring case?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

```
String filterText="abc";
adapter.getFilter().filter(filterText);
```

I want to filter my adapter even if :

```
filterText="Abc";
```

or

```
filterText="aBc";
```

and so on.

Comment: Do you have your own Filer class? There would be a line where the constraint is checked against the list items and you can do a toLower() type function in there.

Comment: I do have my custom filter and it does work, the issue is only case sensitivity.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide the code used here So I provide a sample application code here Refer this for Answer.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ListView mListView;
private CustomAdapter mCustomAdapter;
private EditText mEditText;
private ArrayList<Contacts> _Contacts = new ArrayList<Contacts>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        Contacts contacts = new Contacts();
        contacts.setId(""+i);
        contacts.setName("Name "+i);
        _Contacts.add(contacts);
    }


    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    mCustomAdapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, _Contacts);
    mListView.setAdapter(mCustomAdapter);

    mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            mCustomAdapter.getFilter().filter(arg0);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

        }
    });
}

}
```

CustomAdapter.java

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable{

private ArrayList<Contacts> _Contacts;
private Activity context;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private ValueFilter valueFilter;
private ArrayList<Contacts> mStringFilterList;

public CustomAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Contacts> _Contacts) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
    this._Contacts = _Contacts;
    mStringFilterList =  _Contacts;
    this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     getFilter();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return _Contacts.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return _Contacts.get(position).getName();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

public class ViewHolder {
    TextView tname, tplace;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
        holder.tname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.tplace = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    holder.tname.setText("" + _Contacts.get(position).getName());
    holder.tplace.setText("" + "" + _Contacts.get(position).getId());
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if(valueFilter==null) {

        valueFilter=new ValueFilter();
    }

    return valueFilter;
}
private class ValueFilter extends Filter {

    //Invoked in a worker thread to filter the data according to the constraint.
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults results=new FilterResults();
        if(constraint!=null && constraint.length()>0){
            ArrayList<Contacts> filterList=new ArrayList<Contacts>();
            for(int i=0;i<mStringFilterList.size();i++){
                if((mStringFilterList.get(i).getName().toUpperCase())
                        .contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())) {
                    Contacts contacts = new Contacts();
                    contacts.setName(mStringFilterList.get(i).getName());
                    contacts.setId(mStringFilterList.get(i).getId());
                    filterList.add(contacts);
                }
            }
            results.count=filterList.size();
            results.values=filterList;
        }else{
            results.count=mStringFilterList.size();
            results.values=mStringFilterList;
        }
        return results;
    }


    //Invoked in the UI thread to publish the filtering results in the user interface.
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
            FilterResults results) {
        _Contacts=(ArrayList<Contacts>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
}
```

Contacts.java

```
public class Contacts {

private String name;
private String id;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
android:background="@android:color/black"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:paddingBottom="2dp"
android:paddingTop="2dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:text="Small Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

This is a sample project code. Use this code this will really help you

Comment: Try to post only relevant code... Don't dump as it is

Answer (score 1):

As you are saying you have a custom filter, just modify that..

See the below code:-

```
private class TestFilter extends Filter
{

@Override
protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) 
{
FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> filteredItems = null;

if (constraint != null && constraint.toString().length() > 0) 
{
      for (int index = 0; index < dataSource.getData().size(); index++) 
      {
HashMap<String, Object> existingItem = dataSource.getData().get(index);
String titleString = existingItem.get(dataSource.getSearchKey()).toString();

if(titleString.toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase()))
{
      //please modify the filtering accotding to your code
      HashMap<String, Object> newItem = new HashMap<String, Object>();
      newItem = (HashMap<String, Object>) existingItem.clone();
      newItem.put(ListViewDataSource.SECTION_HEADER_KEY, SEARCH_RESULT);
      filteredItems.add(newItem);
      newItem = null;
}
    }
}
results.values = filteredItems;
return results;
}

@Override
protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,FilterResults results) 
{

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by converting the both strings , i.e what you want to search and from what you are going to search into lowercase. Here is a sample of how I do it.

```
private class InboxFilter extends Filter {
@Override
protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

        constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
        FilterResults result = new FilterResults();
        if (constraint != null && constraint.toString().length() > 0) {
            ArrayList<Inbox> filteredItems = new ArrayList<Inbox>();

            for (int i = 0; i < originalInbox.size(); i++) {
                Inbox inboxItem = originalInbox.get(i);
                if ((inboxItem.getMessage().toString().toLowerCase()
                        .contains(constraint))
                                                            ||(inboxItem.get_group_name()!=null&&inboxItem.get_group_name().toString()
                                                                                                                                      .toLowerCase().contains(constraint))
    || (inboxItem.getfromname()!=null)&&(inboxItem.getfromname().toString()
                                        .toLowerCase().contains(constraint))
                                        || (inboxItem.getfrom()!=null)&&(inboxItem.getfrom().toString()
                                                .toLowerCase().contains(constraint))
                                                || (inboxItem.getTo()!=null)&&(inboxItem.getTo().toString()
                                                .toLowerCase().contains(constraint))){filteredItems.add(inboxItem);}}
            result.count = filteredItems.size();
            result.values = filteredItems;
        } else {
            synchronized (this) {
                result.values = originalInbox;
                result.count = originalInbox.size();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```